# Mysql trigger to remove values from a table and add into another

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, database-trigger

Need Trigger in MySQL db

There are three tables, Orders, Executed, Completed.

'Orders' table with orderid, stockname, price, no of stocks to be purchased, date

```
1, ball, 10, 100, 21/5/16
```

the execution can happen with reference to orderid, in small batches of orders. So when the required no of stocks are bought, lets say in 3 small transactions, which are stored in 'executed' table which the following details

executionid, orderid, stockname, price of purchase, no of stocks purchased, date

```
1,1,ball, 10, 25, 21/5/16

2,1,ball, 10, 25, 22/5/16

3,1,ball, 10, 50, 23/5/16
```

then when the orders are completed,  we need to transfer the order id row from order table to Completed table, which will look like

comepletedid, orderids, executionids, stockname, price of purchase, no of stocks purchased, date

```
1,1,1,ball, 10, 25, 21/5/16

2,1,2,ball, 10, 25, 22/5/16

3,1,3,ball, 10, 50, 23/5/16
```

(order no = executed no with same order id then remove from orders table and put it in completed table), to make sure that orders table has only pending orders not completed orders entries.

How to write this trigger in db code for this - removing values from orders table and inserting them into competed table when the no of stocks to be purchased equal no of stocks purchased.  ex For 100 stocks required to buy, at the level of 50 stocks bought, I want the transaction table updated for 50 stocks and in orders table the required quantity reduced to 50, and then when orders = executed, then remove the data from orders table.

I had a thought on order status column within orders, but dropped the idea as - the orders table would be queried every second almost for executions, its better in the longrun to have orders table only for pending orders not executed orders

```
CREATE TABLE `stocks` (
 `stockid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `stockname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `stockprice` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `availablequantity` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`stockid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `stocks` (`stockid`, `stockname`, `latestassetprice`, `availablequantity`) VALUES
(1, 'ball', '10', '2000');


CREATE TABLE `order` (
 `orderid` INTEGER NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
 `stockname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `stockprice` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `stockquantity` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `orderdate` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderid`)
);

INSERT INTO `order` (`orderid`, `stockname`, `stockprice`, `stockquantity`, `orderdate`) VALUES
(1, 'ball', '10', '100', '23-1-16');

CREATE TABLE `executed` (
 `execid` INTEGER NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
 `orderid` INTEGER NOT NULL,
 `stockname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
 `stockexecprice` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `stockexecutedquantity` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `transactiondate` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`execid`)
);

INSERT INTO `executed` (`execid`, `orderid`, `stockname`, `stockexecprice`, `stockexecutedquantity`, `transactiondate`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'ball',  '10', '25', '21-5-16'),
(2, 1, 'ball',  '10', '25', '22-5-16'),
(3, 1, 'ball',  '10', '50', '23-5-16');


CREATE TABLE `completed` (
 `compid` INTEGER NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
 `orderid` INTEGER NOT NULL,
 `execid` INTEGER NOT NULL,
 `stockname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `stockquantity` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `stockprice` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `orderdate` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `stockexecprice` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `stockexecutedquantity` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `transactiondate` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transid`)
);
```

Comment: Do you mean when the no of stocks ordered equals no of stocks purchased..??

Comment: Where is the no of stocks to be purchased and where is your no of stocks purchased in your db..! You need to save these both values so that you can comapre them with each other and if they are equal so then you can insert the item in completed orders table..!

Comment: you can first fetch row from orders using order_id and then fetch row from executions using order_id and then match the items and if they return same then you can delete the row from orders and INSERT it into completed..

Comment: Why are you using multiple tables instead use one table `orders` and insert a new column namely as `order_status` and add different values which would be used for pending,completed and failed etc..!

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai I have clarified above, in the orders table is the no of stocks to be purchased and in the executed table is the no of stocks purchased in progress. 100 is required and 25+25+50 is purchased. I had a thought on order status, but dropped the  idea as - the orders table would be queried every second almost for executions, its better in the longrun to have orders table only for pending orders not executed orders

Comment: @DhavalChheda yes exactly similar I'm looking in - with addition,ex at the  level of 50 stocks bought, I want the transaction table updated for 50 stocks and in orders table the required quantity reduced to 50, and then when orders = executed, then remove the data from orders table.. I'm finding it difficult to code this within mysql as a function, so that it is robust

Comment: so in this case what you may do is if the value of order stock and execution stock is equal then update completed table with full quantity and delete order table  , if less than update the difference in order table and have transaction table updated with 0 and the completed table updated with transaction table quantity for e.g:- ordered 50 executed 20 so order table = 30 , transaction table 0 and completed table = 20 , once when order table and trans table has same quantity , then delete the order table entry and like before add the quantity from transaction table to the completed table..

Comment: I would prefer to do your task in a transaction in application code, not in a `TRIGGER`.

Comment: You *should* add a status column, it's a much saner design. If you are really worried about slow execution, there's a lot of things you can do to make sure things go fast when the table grows really big. Solve those problem then. You are not unique and "almost every second" is _nothing_ for MySQL. Post another message when you are at a hundred queries per second ;)